# Condicionales con range y decimales en Python no se cumple como debería

Tags: python-3.x

He estado tratando de crear una condicional que me evalue si un número se encuentra en el rango definido. Para esto he usado la función range y arange de la librería numpy.

Todo corre según lo esperado, hasta que intento hacer la misma operación utilizando un número con decimales. Cuando hago ésto, la operacion que evalua la condición no me da el resultado esperado.

```
a = float(5.2)
if a in range(1, 6): print('en rango')
```

De esta manera utilizando numpy:

```
a = float(5.2)
if a in np.arange(1, 7): print('en rango')
```

Answer (score 2):

Y tiene razón. Recuerda que en matemáticas hay infinitos números entre dos fronteras numéricas:
O sea, entre 5 y 6 existen infinitas fracciones de `5.algo`.

`range()` ni `arange()` evalúan subdecimales, a menos que se lo especifiques:

```
>>> list(range(1, 6))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Como ves, en esa colección no se encuentra `5.2`.

Para verificar si `5.2` está entre 2 numeros:

```
>>> 5 < 5.2 < 6 
True
```